# Sequential sum in list by python

Tags: python, list, sum, sequential

I have a table (list of lists) in python like: (Python 3)

```
packets = [[a, b, (0+a), (0+b)], [e, f, (0+a+e), (0+b+f)], [i, j, (0+a+e+i), (0+b+f+j)]]
```

The first column is the size of packets and the second column is time difference.
I want to calculate the total size in third column and sum of time in fourth column.

My code was :

```
for c in range (1, len(packets)):
    packets[c][2] = packets[c-1][2] + packets[c][0]
    packets[c][3] = packets[c-1][3] + packets[c][1]
```

but I got `memoryerror` as the size of `packets` is near a million.

Please suggest me a way to fix this the memory problem.

Comment: Do you really need the partial sum for each packet?

Comment: Yes. the size of my list is around a million.

Comment: I mean why do you store one million of partial sums if you just need the total sum?

Comment: could you please show the error and where you get your memory error?  By the looks of it you should not run into an issue with this code as long as Packets was created ok.  You are just overwriting data in the for loop

Comment: Also, in your example, why is the last packet different from others?

Comment: I meant the line of code your error points to I'm trying to determine where you get the error.  I would suggest trying out a generator for memory issues, but I don't think a million of those packets are going to cause a memory issue, something else is going on here

Comment: As I need to plot the graph for network's behaviour i need to have the sum.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 35, in <module>
    packets[c][2]=packets[c-1][2]+packets[c][0]
MemoryError

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the xrange function instead of range:

```
for c in xrange(1,len(packets)):
    packets[c][2]=packets[c-1][2]+packets[c][0]
    packets[c][3]=packets[c-1][3]+packets[c][1]
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange

**Edit**

If you can't use `xrange`, then make your own:

```
def myrange(start, end):
    while True:
        if start == end:
            break
        yield start
        start += 1

for i in myrange(1, 10):
    print i
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but as xrange doesn't exist in Python 3.0 I need to fix it in other way.

Comment: @user3636424 then please state in your question that you are using Python 3